# How can I click on a button if it has only value and name attributes using Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the form and I want to click on submit button using Javascript Programatically

```html
<form action="/testseries/go" method="post">
  <div class="key">
    <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Phone Number" required="">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login"> //THIS BUTTON
</form>
```

The Problem is that I am new in Javascript and i have studied that
there are DOM elements like `getElementById` , `ClassName` etc but in this
case how can I get the click of  the button which don't have any DOM?

Comment: If you are ok with using jquery you can use triger function to execute actions programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('form > input[type="submit"]');
console.log(input.value);
```

```html
<form action="/testseries/go" method="post">
  <div class="key">
    <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Phone Number" required="">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login"> //THIS BUTTON
</form>
```

In plain language, `'form > input[type="submit"]'` means select `input` which has an attribute `type` whose value is `submit` that is a child of a `form`.

Comment: VM1598:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'input' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM1598:1

Comment: You have some other Javascript that you haven't posted here that uses the `input` variable name, just use a different name

Comment: I am trying your provided piece of code on my browser console directly ..there is no other code

Comment: Try running Javascript in a `<script>` tag instead. Use a different variable name if you have to, `formInput` or whatever you want

Comment: I have changed the variable name and it works but it has not solved my problem ..as I said I need to click on the button using code but it is just showing Login in console ..is there any method like onclick or click through which I can get the click event ?

Comment: Once you've selected the element, the rest should be trivial - just assign to its `onclick` property, or add a click listener

Comment: Bingo...... const inas = document.querySelector('form [type="submit"]');
console.log(inas.value); inas.click();   You are a genius java script geek man .. :)

Comment: can you tell me some of the reference sites or stuffs through which I can also learn this type of cool stuffs ?

Answer (score 0):

[**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) is used to reference the`<form>` tag and all of its **[form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Forms)**. HFCC can be used very effectively with minimal code. Compare these two snippets which are equivalent:

**HFCC** - 108 Chars

```
var log = document.forms.login;
var L = log.elements;
var b0 = L.btn0;
var b1 = L.btn1;
var s0 = L.sub0;
```

**Standard** - 231 Chars

```
var log = document.getElementById('login');
var L = document.querySelectorAll('input, button');
var b0 = document.getElementById('btn0');
var b1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var s0 = document.getElementById('sub0');
```

---

The JavaScript methods for triggering a click is [**`click()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click):

```
targetObj.click();
```

and for triggering a submit is [**`submit()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

```
formObj.submit();
```

---

**In the following Demo:**

- Sends submitted data to a [live test server](https://httpbin.org). A response will be sent back. There should be values of keys: `[username]` and `[password]` if successful.

  ```
  "form":{"password":"|PASSWORD ENTERED|","username":"|NAME ENTERED|"},
  ```
- The 2 buttons at the button test the triggers.

  - Click the <kbd>Trigger Click</kbd>. If both text fields have content, then you should receive a response from the live test server. Otherwise you'll get a tooltip requesting the indicated textbox have data.
  - Click the <kbd>Trigger Submit</kbd>. The form will be sent regardless of textbox content. The reason for this behavior is because the `<form>` element is the `event.target` of a submit event and `required` attributes are internally triggered by a click event on a `submit` button, hence the behavior of the previous trigger.

---

### Demo

---

```js
var log = document.forms.login;
var L = log.elements;
var b0 = L.btn0;
var b1 = L.btn1;
var s0 = L.sub0;

b0.onclick = function(e) {
  s0.click();
}

b1.onclick = function(e) {
  log.submit();
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

label,
input,
i {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 5px;
}

i {
  transform: translateY(8px)
}

input[type='submit'] {
  margin-left: 75%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<form id='login' action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required><br>

    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>

    <input id='sub0' type="submit" value="Login">
  </fieldset>
<button id='btn0' type='button'>Trigger Click</button>
<button id='btn1' type='button'>Trigger Submit</button>
</form>
```